# Specific element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I find specific element of an array?

For example, I have an array filled with 400 elements:

```
double Array1[400];
```

In another array let

```
double Array2[380];
```

I want to have values of `Array1` from position `20`.

How can I do this (current position - 20th position)?

In short, I want to fill `Array2` with values of `Array 1` from position `[20]` to `[400]`.

Comment: Hint: the expression `Array1[20]` is equivalent to `*(Array1 + 20)`. And read about [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: Did you do any research?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/):

> Copies the elements in the range [first,last) into the range beginning
>   at result.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(Array1 + 20, Array1 + 400, Array2);
```

Comment: or `memcpy( Array2, Array1 + 20, sizeof(double) * 380);`

Comment: The question is tagged C++, not C though :-)

Comment: still perfectly usable in cpp ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 380; i++)
{
    Array2[i] = *(Array1 + 20 + i);
}
```

Comment: This is the same as @Cyber's answer, but with pointer arithmetic.